# Writing >20 bytes to an external Bluetooth device in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have an external device that communicates via **Bluetooth** with an **iPhone Application** that has support for **iOS6+**.

The problem is that I need to write more than **20 bytes** to a characteristic and from what I've read and tried this is not possible using **BLE**.

Here is a basic structure of my method:

```
NSData * payload = ... //53 bytes, last 2 bytes CRC
[peripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

The error I get when sending >20 bytes is `CBErrorOperationCancelled` (code 5) and `CBErrorConnectionTimeout` (code 6). I believe this is normal.

I divided the data in **chunks of 20 bytes** (example here: https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/issues/8) and the data is not written well on the device:

```
NSData * chunk1 = ... //first 20 bytes
NSData * chunk2 = ... //next 20 bytes
...
NSData * chunkN = ... //remaining bytes + CRC from whole data

[peripheral writeValue:chunk1 forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
[peripheral writeValue:chunk2 forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
...
[peripheral writeValue:chunkN forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I think the external device treats each byte array, not the whole data.

Also, I tried to split the payload data in chunks of 18 bytes and **append the CRC** to each chunk of bytes I send. This got me the same result as in appending CRC to the last chunk of data.

In the **Android version** of the application the whole data is sent, so I know that the device can read **>20 bytes** on a single command.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to send the whole data in chunks to the external
   device without modifying the peripherals hardware / software?
2. Is there a flag / signal byte in the first chunk of data that notifies
       the device the length of the whole message?
3. I've read that in iOS 7 is possible to send a larger byte array. If
   I make support for iOS 7+ will it solve my problem?
4. What alternatives do I have to CB?

Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks!

**EDIT**

When I try sending data in chunks like in the [BTLE sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) I get the following response:

```
// NSLog - data that is written on the peripheral
// Chunk 1 : <2047d001 0f002000 315b0011 b4425543 41524553>
// Chunk 2 : <54202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020>
// Chunk 3 : <20202020 2009059b 56210988 b9b50408 02c7123d>

// Write to peripheral
[self.twCurrentPeripheral writeValue:chunk1 forCharacteristic:self.twCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
[self.twCurrentPeripheral writeValue:chunk2 forCharacteristic:self.twCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
[self.twCurrentPeripheral writeValue:chunk3 forCharacteristic:self.twCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

// NSLog - Response from peripheral
// Data update char : <20470000 04d00101 00ab42>
// Data update char : <204700>
// Data update char : <0004d001 0100ab42>
// Data update char : <204700>
// Data update char : <0504d001 032c6bcf>
```

The correct response should be (like in the Android version):

```
// Response <20470000 04d00101 00ab42>
// Response <20470000 04d00105 006786>
```

Comment: You could break the message into multiple parts.  I don't do iOS stuff, but assuming it really is just that >20 bytes isn't happy, you could get around it by simple segmenting the data.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner the device treats each chunk of data as a command, it doesn't wait for the last segment. I don't know if I need to signal the length of each packet or the whole message and where to append this byte flag.

Comment: Just check out the [BTLETransfer sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) it does exactly what you want to.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't work like that. Analyze the BTLE example a little further. You'll see that a more transmission control has to be implemented in your app, simply sending write requests sequentially will most probably fail. Also, check out other related SO questions, we have answered these issues many times. The Core Bluetooth Programming Guide also contains useful info.

Comment: @allprog The peripheral is external, I don't have access to its software or hardware. In the BTLE example, they developed the peripheral backend (because is running on an iOS device) and they can listen to an EOM. The Android version of the app uses a RFCOMM connection with the device.

Comment: The RFCOMM is serial connection with transmission control. The BLE CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse is more like UDP. If you send too fast, stuff may get lost. Use CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse for all write operations to make sure that all data arrives at the destination.

Comment: @allprog I get the same result.

Comment: Do I need to enrol to MFI Program to send >20 bytes to this external device?

Comment: No, BLE is not tied to MFi. Have you tried to delay your writes? E.g. send the requests with 10-20 ms delays inbetween.

Comment: @allprog Yes, with dispatch_after.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that the peripheral handles separate writes with appending the parts?

Comment: Actually, you can send at most 512 bytes in theory. On the peripheral side you need to split in chunks but on the central side this should not be required. The API is not built the same way as in the peripheral. Have you tried without splitting? Sorry, I'm have to poke around too to find the solution.

Comment: @allprog Without splitting I get error code 5 (CBErrorOperationCancelled)

Comment: Do you have a description of the peripheral's BLE interface? Does it provide examples for what use cases it supports?

Comment: @allprog Not much... the structure of writing to flash is like so: 0xD001 (command) + 3 bytes (address_start) + 1 byte (number of bytes to write) + bytes to write. I just tried the following logic: write_to_address_chunk_01 + get_free_address + write_to_nxt_address_chunk_02 + ... I get error code 6 (CBErrorConnectionTimeout)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to figure out the exact protocol specific to the peripheral you are using. If you find out the details, I can probably help you implement it in Core Bluetooth.

Comment: @allprog are there any alternatives? My goal is to send > 20 bytes via BH Connection. Any private frameworks, apis, different connection support for sending data >20 bytes from iOS to a non iOS device ?

Comment: @allprog I will try with BluetoothManager SDK. If you have other thoughts let me know.

Comment: I think the scenario you are trying either works with Core Bluetooth or it won't work anyway. My connection info is in my SO profile page. I don't know if I could help but feel free to contact me to discuss stuff in private.

Comment: @allprog You were right, it doesn't work. I also tried with a socket connection and no luck. I am stuck :( . Please provide an answer so I can close this question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added an answer for what I think is the case. Unfortunately, without knowing any details of the device you use, it's hard to tell the truth.

Comment: @allprog If you still want to help, please let me know how can I get in touch with you. You can get my email from my SO profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to chunk the data in 20 byte length pieces, you got that part right. If you use the "write with response" method, then before sending the next piece of data, you should wait for the `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` callback to happen on your peripheral delegate before sending the next piece. In case of "write without response", you should wait before sending out the next chunk. The stuff you add in the in the writeValue call will be buffered. If the buffer is full, then your call will be dropped.

Comment: "In case of "write without response", you should wait before sending out the next chunk." - How long should you wait and why? Does writeValue:(...) not finish writing before returning? Is there no buffering or queue?

Comment: @DarrenBlack please check out the last two sentences in my answer. With write without response you don't get notified when it happened or if it happened at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data in 20 bytes chanks. Each packet should be at the size of 20 bytes. The other side (the BLE central) should accept the packets and save them until he gets all the packets he was waiting for. For this to happen you will have to create some kind of protocol:
Sending the type of message then the length of the message in bytes and the centeral should read this header and then save the "length" bytes he is waiting for in this message and then parse the entire data.

Note that IOS might fail sending some of the packets when there are many packets to send very fast, so when calling

```
 success = [self.peripheral updateValue:chunk forCharacteristic:myChar onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
```

success will tell you if the send was successful, if it was not you need to resend this packet. 
in that case you should implement the IOS BLE protocol `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`

and at the method `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers` you should retry sending the same packet again.

Comment: I'm writing the BLE Central which run on iOS device, not the peripheral